# Order By values column CSV Java

Tags: java, csv, sorting

I have a csv file formed by two attributes: the first of type string and the second of type double.

Starting from this csv file, I would like to obtain another one, however, increasingly ordered based on the value of the second attribute. In SQL there was the `ORDER BY` function that allowed to order a database based on the specified attribute, I would like to get the same result as the `ORDER BY`.

Example input CSV file:

```
tricolor;14.0
career;9.0
salty;1020.0
looks;208.0
bought;110.0
```

Expected output CSV file:

```
career;9.0
tricolor;14.0
bought;110.0
looks;208.0
salty;1020.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the CSV file into an `List` of `Object[]` (one `Object[]` per line in your CSV file)

- First element of the array is the line itself (a String)
- Second element of the array is the value of the double (a Double)

so you have the following list:

```
{ 
  ["tricolor;14.0", 14.0], 
  ["career;9.0", 9.0], 
  ["salty;1020.0", 1020.0],
  ["looks;208.0", 208.0],
  ["bought;110.0", 110.0]
}
```

Then sort it based on the value of the double

And you can then write it back to a CSV file (only writing the first element of each array)

```
List<Object[]> list = readFile("myFile.csv");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(p -> (Double)p[1]));
// write to csv file, just printing it out here
list.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0]));
```

The method to read the file:

```
private static List<Object[]> readFile(String fileName) {
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String line;
        String[] splitLine;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            splitLine = line.split(";");
            // add an array, first element is the line itself, second element is the double value
            list.add(new Object[] {line, Double.valueOf(splitLine[1])});
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

**EDIT** If you want reverse order:

Once you have your sorted list, you can reverse it using the convenient `reverse` method on the `Collections` class

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Comment: one last thing. How should I modify `list.sort (Comparator.comparing (p -> (Integer) p [1]));` so that the ordering is decreasing rather than increasing?

Comment: @user3062889 I added an edit regarding reversing the list. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the general approach of parsing the file into a sorted map (e.g. `TreeMap`), then iterating the map and writing back out to file.

```
TreeMap<String, Double> map = new TreeMap<String, Double>();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("yourfile.csv"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        map.put(parts[0], Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}

// now write the map to file, sorted ascending in alphabetical order

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("yourfileout.csv");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        bw.write(entry.getKey() + ";" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
```

Notes:

- I assume that the string values in the first column would always be unique.  If there could be duplicates, the above script would have to be modified to use a map of lists, or something along those lines.
- I also assume that the string values would all be lowercase.  If not, then you might not get the sorting you expect.  One solution, should this be a problem, would be to lowercase (or uppercase) every string before inserting that key into the map.

Comment: Thanks. The string values are unique and lowercase.I would like the sort on the numerical value of the second second column or based on the number. I tried to run it and I get the following error: `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 2` at the line of code:
`while ((line = br.readLine ())! = null) {`
What can be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

get comma separated values into the `LinkedHashMap`

```
TreeMap<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("yourfile.csv"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        map.put(parts[0], Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
}
```

then sort the `map` based on double values.

try with java 8,

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Double> sortedMap;
sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```